# Предустановка в поле AsFloat (DataSet) знака минус

Tags: база-данных, delphi, firebird

Есть *DataSet*, с полем «*Number*» типа *Double Precision* с привязанным *DBEdit*, перед вставкой значения в это поле, заполняется еще одно поле «*Main*» и производится расчет результатом которого может стать отрицальное число.
Исходя из отрицательного значения, мне в поле «*Number*» нужно забить один знак «-».

Вставить в *DataSet* однин знак «-», не получается, поэтому приходится воспользоваться *DBEdit* и туда забивать «-», но когда я кнопкой «*Tab*» или мышкой, перехожу в поле «*Number*» ( чтобы забить значение) знак «-» убивается.
Мне бы хотелось чтобы знак «-» оставался, после того как я перешел в это поле курсором, чтобы забить только значение (в результате значение будет отрицательным).

Можно конечно использовать обычный *Edit*, и после ввода значения в *Edit* переносить отрицательное значение в поле «*Number*», но как-то это не хорошо выглядит.

Comment: Нет такого числа «-».

Comment: Что ж тогда, остановлюсь на дополнительном *Edit*, т.е. наложу его поверх *dbEdit*. И когда в *Edit*, после "-" буду вводить цифры, то буду переносить все в *dbEdit* (событие "*OnChange*")